# Exact Syntax for passing char array (typed out in a method parameter)

Tags: java

`doPrompt({'a','t','q'},"Test");`

I get a illegal start of expression error starting with the `{` character.

Here is the method being called:

```
public static char doPrompt(char[] validCharacterValues, String prompt) {
    do {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        Scanner keyboardMonster = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usersInput = keyboardMonster.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (arrayContains(validCharacterValues,usersInput.charAt(0)))
            return usersInput.charAt(0);
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332535/how-to-pass-array-as-parameter-in-java-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays can be created inline with `new type[]{}` with `type` being the type of the array.
So for your case, it would be `doPrompt(new char[]{'a','t','q'},"Test");`

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it like this:

```
doPrompt(new char[]{'t', 'j', 'k'}, "Test");
```